# Accessing a database simultaneously from multiple applications using Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

If I use Sequel in a Ruby app like this:

```
DB = Sequel.sqlite('testdb.db')
```

does it make the database shared? Can I acces this same file from a different ruby app AT THE SAME TIME and get the database to perform locking etc?

I'm thinking probably not and i'd have to actually have a separate instance of the database running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use a file backed database, you can access it by multiple processes.  They don't even have to be ruby processes.  Note that in SQLite, writers block all readers, so multi-process or multi-threaded write performance is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

This is not up to neither Ruby nor Sequel. It's up to sqlite. Take a look at [sqlite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5), and see whether it answers your question.